# IFs y Else If me genera resultado inesperado en Python

Tags: python-3.7

Tengo un error en vez de salir el angulo desconocido me sale es obtuso cuando ingreso un valor que no establecí, ayuden :(

Aquí les dejo mi código, es una tarea :C

```
#Decoracion: Nombre del algoritmo
print("------------------------------------------------")
print("IDENTIFICAR EL TIPO DE ANGULO.")
print("------------------------------------------------")

Grados=input("Ingresar un numero en grados para identificar que tipo de angulo es: ")

if Grados =='90':
        print("Es un Ángulo recto")
elif Grados =='180':
        print("Es un Ángulo llano")
elif Grados =='360':
        print("Es un Ángulo completo")
elif Grados =='0':
        print("Es un Ángulo nulo")
elif Grados <'90':
        print("Es un Ángulo agudo")
elif Grados >'90':
        print("Es un Ángulo obtuso")
elif Grados <'180':
        print("Es un Ángulo obtuso ")
elif Grados >'180':
        print("Es un Ángulo cóncavo")
elif Grados <'360':
        print("Es un Ángulo cóncavo ")

else:
print("Es un Ángulo desconocido")

print("Fin.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Hay unos cuantos pequeños problemas con tu código que están afectando el funcionamiento

Como te habrás dado cuenta, el `input()` siempre devuelve un `string` (Supongo que por eso en tus `if` estás comparando con `string`), pero lo que hay que tomar en cuenta es que al comparar `string` se evalúa el valor [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) que tienen los caracteres

Por ejemplo, si ejecuto la siguiente línea

```
print(max('20', '150'))
```

Tal vez esperarías que devolviera `'150'` pero en realidad devuelve `'20'`. Esto es porque el valor del primer caracter de cada elemento es 2 cuyo valor ASCII es 50 y del segundo es 1 cuyo valor ASCII es 49, entonces al comparar quien es el mayor el resultado devuelve `'20'` porque 50 es mayor que 49

Algo similar está sucediendo con tu código, esto es porque usas `string` para comparar valores numéricos. Para corregirlo primero puedes convertir el valor del `input()` a tipo entero `int` o `float` si quisieras que considerara valores con decimales

Esto lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma (Convirtiendo a `float`, si deseas entero entonces sustituye por `int`):

```
Grados = float(input("Ingresar un numero en grados para identificar que tipo de angulo es: "))
```

Ahora ya tenemos valores numéricos por lo que podemos quitar las comillas de todos los valores de los `if` y `elif`

Segundo problema, cuando deseas comparar que una variable este entre un rango de valores, debes incluir las dos comparaciones en el mismo `if`

```
if (a > 0) and (a < 90):
```

Si lo haces en una combinación de `if` con `elif`, por ejemplo:

```
if a > 0:
    print('Primera condición')
elif a < 90:
    print('Segunda condición')
```

La segunda condición núnca sería válida ya que cualquier número que sea mayor a `0` validaría la primera condición, es por eso que cuando quieres comparar si un valor está entre un valor mínimo y un máximo se debe hacer en un solo `if` o `elif`, es decir, en la misma condición

En python existe otra forma de hacer la comparación entre un limite superior e inferior que es más fácil de leer y entender

```
if 0 < Grados < 90:
```

Es decir, grados debe ser mayor a 0 pero menor a 90, esto te ayudará a disminuir un poco tu código y que sea más entendible

Ejemplo completo:

```
Grados = float(input("Ingresar un numero en grados para identificar que tipo de angulo es: "))

if Grados == 90:
        print("Es un Ángulo recto")
elif Grados == 180:
        print("Es un Ángulo llano")
elif Grados == 360:
        print("Es un Ángulo completo")
elif Grados == 0:
        print("Es un Ángulo nulo")
elif 0 < Grados < 90:
        print("Es un Ángulo agudo")
elif 90 < Grados < 180:
        print("Es un Ángulo obtuso")
elif 180 < Grados < 360:
        print("Es un Ángulo cóncavo")
else:
    print("Es un Ángulo desconocido")

print("Fin.")
```

**Nota:** En tu pregunta no especificas qué hacer si los valores son menores a 0 o mayores a 360, en el código que puse los detecta como ángulo desconocido, pero en realidad lo que podrías hacer es recalcular  el ángulo, por ejemplo, si tuvieras 380°, desde el la posición absoluta sería un ángulo de 20° y podrías clasificarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya logre solucionar y perfeccionar, ahora funciona todo tal cual. mil gracias.

Comment: @DanielFlow, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)